# Doctrine not counting null values at comparison

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have such a query:

```
 $thism = new \DateTime('first day of this month midnight');

    $parameters = array('thism' => $thism, 'user' => $user,'status'=>1);

    return $this->createQueryBuilder('q')
        ->select('count(q)')
        ->where('q.createdAt > :thism')
        ->andWhere('q.user = :user')
        ->andWhere('q.completed != :status')
        ->setParameters($parameters)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

This should count all my incomplete objects from this month. The problem is with `q.completed != :status`. This will not count objects that have `completed=NULL`. Completed is a boolean value

```
class Quote
{

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="completed", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $completed;
}
```

Have I done something wrong, or why doesn't Doctrine count NULL as being different than TRUE?

I've tried replacing `'status'=>1` with `1,true,TRUE`, both with and without quotes and still no effect.

Formatted query:

```
SELECT count(q0_.id) AS sclr_0 FROM quote q0_ WHERE q0_.created_at > ? AND q0_.user_id = ? AND q0_.completed <> ?
Parameters: ['2016-04-01 00:00:00', '1', 1]

SELECT count(q0_.id) AS sclr_0 FROM quote q0_ WHERE q0_.created_at > '2016-04-01 00:00:00' AND q0_.user_id = '1' AND q0_.completed <> 1;
```

Comment: what does generated SQL look like ? (you can see it in log)

Comment: @Miro added it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Null in MySQL is not the same as true or false. 
More info on that [on MySQL official site.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html)

Your query in translation to SQL will be:

```
SELECT count(1) 
FROM <some table>
WHERE completed != 1
AND createdAt > '01042016 00:00'
AND user = 'some_user'
```

If you want to query for null values too in SQL you should have a query such as:

```
SELECT count(1) 
FROM <some table>
WHERE 
   ( completed != 1 or completed is NULL)
AND createdAt > '01042016 00:00'
AND user = 'some_user'
```

If you need this column by default to have some value - you can define it in MySQL by using `default 0` (or any other value) in your `CREATE TABLE` statement like that:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(
   ...

   completed tinyint(1) default 0
   ....
)
```

If you do that - your query should work with no change.

Comment: `Null in MySQL is not the same as true or false`. Strange thing that I didn't know. This can screw a lot of queries if one does not pay attention to it.

Comment: If you need null values to be treated as 0 - you should set the default

Comment: However for already existing null values, the values will remain null after a schema update.

Comment: yes. you need to perform an update of all records after you make the change. You should use `update your table set status=0 where status is null`